# Multithreaded TCP server with C sockets and pthreads - Why does accept() block on the second request?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, server, pthreads

I've been writing a small multithreaded TCP server in C using unix sockets and pthreads, but I'm having trouble with accept(). It hangs on the second request that comes through, and only unblocks when the previously thread exits.

Here's how I set up the server socket.

```
int server_start(server_t *server, int port) {
    int fd;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;

    // Socket file descriptor.
    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("socket failed");
        return 1;
    }

    // Socket address.
    server_addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server_addr.sin_port        = htons(port);

    // Bind.
    if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == -1) {
        perror("bind failed");
        return 1;
    }

    server->fd = fd;
    listen(server->fd, server->clients_len);
    pthread_create(&(server->thread), NULL, thread_entry_server, server);

    return 0;
}
```

Here's my add_client code. It spawns a separate thread for the client.

```
client_t *server_add_client(server_t *server) {

    int iter,
        fd,
        status;
    client_t *client;

    printf("before\n");
    fd = accept(server->fd, NULL, 0);
    printf("after\n");

    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("accept");
        return NULL; // Connection failed.
    }

    // Find an empty spot.
    client = server->get_empty_spot();
    client->fd = fd;

    // Start the new thread.
    status = pthread_create(
        &(client->thread),
        NULL,
        thread_entry_client,
        client
    );
    if (status != 0) {
        perror("pthread_create");
        close(client->fd);
        return NULL;
    }

    client->active = 1;

    return client;
}
```

And here's my entry function for the client thread:

```
void *thread_entry_client(void *void_client) {

    client_t *client = void_client;
    int len;

    while (1) {

        len = recv(client->fd, client->recv_buffer, RECV_BUFFER_LEN, 0);
        if (len < 0) {
            perror("recv");
            client->active = 0;
            close(client->fd);
            return NULL;
        }
        if (len == 0) { // Client disconnected.
            client->active = 0;
            close(client->fd);
            printf("disconnect\n");
            return NULL;
        }

        if (len > 0) {
            //printf("%s\n", client->recv_buffer);
            printf("msg\n");
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

So what I'm doing to test this is establishing two connections. The first connection goes through and works fine, but the second connection does not - instead the thread hangs on accept(). I know this from my printfs (that I've left in there), and I know that accept() unblocks AFTER the first client disconnects. I also know that my code is not closing the server socket file descriptor or changing it.

Any advice on debugging this? I can't figure it out.

EDIT: Here is thread_entry_server.

```
void *thread_entry_server(void *void_server) {
    server_t *server = void_server;
    client_t *client;

    while (1) {
        client = server_add_client(server);
        if (client == NULL) // Server is full or connection failed.
            continue;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `pthread_create()` pass `server_add_client` instead of `thread_entry_server`?

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to include thread_entry_server. I'll add it.

Comment: accept() won't return until an incoming TCP connection is received; what is it that is connect()'ing to the port that accept() is listening on?

Comment: Aaand that's it. I've been connecting with a JS websocket, I just tried telnet and that worked as expected.

I haven't done any handshaking stuff with the websocket yet, so that must have been it. I wouldn't have expected that kind of behavior though. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Side note: creating a new thread per connection is a bit resource intensive and might break down under heavier loads... I would consider `epoll` / `kqueue` or an existing library. If this is a toy project, it doesn't really matter. If you're planning to use this in an actual application, I would recommend rethinking the design.

Comment: Definitely a toy, but thanks for the advice :D I may look into those.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `accept()` will block (unless configured otherwise) till a client connection is available.

See [Documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/accept.html) which mentions -

> If the listen queue is empty of connection requests and O_NONBLOCK is
>   not set on the file descriptor for the socket, accept() will block
>   until a connection is present. If the listen() queue is empty of
>   connection requests and O_NONBLOCK is set on the file descriptor for
>   the socket, accept() will fail and set errno to [EAGAIN] or
>   [EWOULDBLOCK].

Also, `server->get_empty_spot();` should always return new `client` instance otherwise it would mean you are passing same `client->thread` to `pthread_create`.

I usually prefer to create new thread myself, something like -

```
**pthread_t newListner;**
ThreadArgs thread_args;
thread_args.client_socket = client_socket;

int rc;

if ((rc = pthread_create(&newListner, NULL, startListener, &thread_args)))
{ .. }
```

Give it a try.

Comment: I'm aware of that, and that is the behavior I want. The problem is that when I am connecting again (with the first connection still open), accept continues to block. It only unblocks when the first client disconnects.

Comment: I should have been more clear in my post, updating it.

Answer (score 0):

I was testing with a javascript websocket, but I wasn't doing any handshaking so it wasn't completing the connection. Testing with telnet works.